# How to widen 'cells' in a correlation matrix?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, correlation

I made a correlation matrix with `ggplot` and `geom_tile`, where the values are the correlations.

However, the labels on my x-axis overlap with each other slightly. Rather than reduce my font size, *how can I increase the width of the 'cells'* so that my axis labels can have more space?

I am working in R Markdown and ultimately am saving the figure as a PDF. In my current chunk name I have `fig.height =9` .

Comment: I'd play around with the `dpi` setting, which affects the relative sizes of graphics vs text in quite predictable way.

Comment: Can you post a working version of your code?